# Materialviewpager can't find referenced method

Tags: java, android, android-glide

What is wrong here?

Code:

```
viewPager = (MaterialViewPager)  findViewById(R.id.viewpager_home);
tabLayout = (TabLayout)  findViewById(R.id.tabs_home_page);
ViewPager viewPager2 = viewPager.getViewPager();

tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager2);
//After set an adapter to the ViewPager
viewPager.getPagerTitleStrip().setViewPager(viewPager.getViewPager());

List<String> head=new ArrayList<>();
String subcatlist="";
for(int i=0;i<subcat_newList.size();i++){
    head.add(subcat_newList.get(i).getName());
    subcatlist+=head.get(i);
}


Log.e("imp_140_pl","sub cat found "+subcatlist+"   "+getCategoary());
setupViewPager(viewPager2,subcat_newList);
```

Log output:

> Warning:com.github.florent37.materialviewpager.header.MaterialViewPagerImageHelper$1:  'com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target into(android.widget.ImageView)' in program class com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder
>   `Warning:The`android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.
>   Warning:com.github.florent37.materialviewpager.header.MaterialViewPagerImageHelper$1: can't find referenced method 'com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target into(android.widget.ImageView)' in program class com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder
>   Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>   Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
>   Job failed, see logs for details

Dependencies:

```
compile 'com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.3'
compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
```

Proguard:

```
> -dontwarn com.github.siyamed.**
> -keep class com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.**{ *; }
> -keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
> -keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
> -keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {   **[] $VALUES;   public *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a proguard issue since it is failing on `':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'`.  Looking at the library for glide their proguard file has the following: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/proguard-rules.txt

```
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
```

Comment: What is your compile sdk version

Comment: minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: compileSdkVersion 26